# Is this the correct way of translating this math formula into a c function?

Tags: c, math

I'm having some trouble with my functions and when I looked back over my code, I remembered that I wasn't too sure if I translated this math formula correctly.

Note: If the parameters, x and y aren't in the interval [1, 20], then the function should return a -1.

[image]

Here's my code for that function:

```
double irrigationExposure(int x, int y) {
   double denominator, fraction, waterexp, wexp;

   if (x >= 1 && x <= 20 && y >= 1 && y <= 20) {
      denominator = (1 + (abs(x - y)))* (1.0);
      fraction = ((IRRIEXPONUM)/(denominator));

      waterexp = (fraction) + (2);

      if (waterexp <= 10) {
         wexp = waterexp;
      }

      else {
         wexp = 2.0;
      }
   }

   else {
      wexp = -1.0;
   }

   return wexp;
}
```

Comment: A number of things are a bit odd (e.g. why multiply by 1 in the denominator? why so many parentheses?) but one particular issue - where does `IRRIEXPONUM` come from?

Comment: IRRIEXPONUM would be a constant that I declare before this, so it'll be 10 in this case. I multiplied by 1 in the denominator because dividing an integer by an integer will give me an integer value BUT, if you look at the function declaration, I want a double as the return value. So that's why I multiplied by 1.0 in the denominator, to make it into a double value.

Comment: Yes I figured that out before commenting, but that's not the point. I can't know if your code is correct if I can't see it all, and just because there's a reason why you multiplied by 1.0 doesn't mean you achieved your goal in a clear, readable way. Multiplying by one suggests you intend to multiply by one, whereas a cast suggests you intend to cast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that you want the maximum value to be 10, then

```
if (waterexp <= 10) {
     wexp = waterexp;
  }

  else {
     wexp = 2.0;
  }
}
```

should be

```
if (waterexp <= 10) {
     wexp = waterexp;
  }

  else {
     wexp = 10.0;
  }
}
```

Otherwise if `waterexp > 10` your answer would be 2, not 10.

Comment: Actually I wouldn't do the above at all. If the exposure value cannot be higher than 10, then that is a misuse of the function. I would not like for the application to just silently substitute the value I thought I provided with something it can use for its calculation. Much better to fail with an error of some kind.

Comment: So would I have to put another if statement after the first one for when waterexp is greater than 10? I thought that the else statement was for when waterexp would be greater than 10? And Lasse V. Karlsen, in that case, how would you write a function that satisfies the above formula??

Comment: @Karen No you don't need another `if` statement, the `else` you already have covers the situation where `waterexp > 10`, it just returns sets the wrong value in the function you wrote.